# it seems i bought bitcoins but they weren't associated to by wallet.. is this possible?

Tags: wallet-recovery

my wallet has the same receiving address in the unused addresses as the bitcoin transaction in the blockchain however the bitcoins are not in my wallet. How can I recover them.

Comment: Can you share the transaction id? It maybe pending confirmation?

Comment: What wallet software are you using?